# Windows 7 refuses to accept file transfers via Bluetooth

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, file-transfer

I have 3 machines with Bluetooth;

- Desktop running Windows 2000 with a USB dongle
- Laptop running Windows XP with a USB dongle
- Laptop running Windows 7 with Bluetooth built in

I can send and receive files between the Windows 2000 and XP machines, and I can send files from Windows 7 to Windows 2000 and XP machines, but there is no way the Windows 7 machine will accept transfers.

The best I can get with the Windows 7 machine is a dialog Windows that pops up saying `filename.xxx.lnk` is transferring and gives me an option to pick a directory on the Windows 7 machine but when I click "finish" nothing happens and no file is transferred.

Answer (score 6):

By default Windows 7 does not accept the receiving connection from bluetooth devices you have to run a command, open the run dialog box through Windows+<kbd>R</kbd> key and type the `fsquirt` in the box and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. Now you have a dialog with two options that will ask you which one you want to perform. Now select the `Receive files` option for batch receiving.

[image]

Or you can click on the system tray bluetooth icon and right click on it and then you can select the option `Receive file` but it will receive only one file as I think.

Comment: Thanks ! Don't know why there isn't a simpler way to open this fquirt window through the control panel or bluetooth panel or something

Comment: There are no "receive file" option on my BT icon, but your instructions worked just fine.

Answer (score -1):

I know this is super-late,ubut I'd thought I'd mention that I, at least, have a bluetooth icon in the... what is that, the notifications bar, right-hand corner by the clock (if using the default start bar position).  I usually have to open the little "more icons" arrow to find it, but when you click or right-click it brings up a menu.  The fifth option down, "Recieve a File," brings up that window to choose whether to receive or share. :)
(Sorry, I'm on my phone and can't figure out how to insert a picture.) Anyway, I guess if you didn't see it before, you probably don't have it, but maybe this will help someone else! :)

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of [the other answer](http://superuser.com/a/435089/302463), specifically the part at the end, after the image.